# bash command not running through python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have the following method:

```
def _run_command(bash_command: str) -> str:
    """
    Run a bash command.

    Args:
        bash_command: command to be executed.
    """
    logging.info(f"Running {bash_command}.")
    process = subprocess.Popen(bash_command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    if error is not None:
        logging.exception(f"Error running command: {bash_command}")
        raise ValueError(error)

    return str(output)
```

Which I use to run shell commands through Python. It seems to work for the majority of the cases except for this one:

```
command = f'find {self._prefix} -name "*.txt" -type f -delete'
output = self._run_command(command)
```

Where `self._prefix` is a path such as `/opt/annotations/`. I'd expect this command to delete all txt files inside that path, which is not happening. However, if I run this command `find /opt/annotations/ -name "*.txt" -type f -delete` directly in the terminal, everything is erased as expected. So I'm wondering if I'm missing something here.

The logging shows the expect command, however, the txts aren't erased:

`2020-11-18 19:07:47 fm-101 root[10] INFO Running find /opt/annotations/ -name "*.txt" -type f -delete.`

Comment: `/opt/annotations` ≠ `\opt\annotations`! On POSIX, these are completely different paths. Furthermore, you can’t just `split()` a shell command on whitespace, you’re bound to run into trouble with that in the long run. But with correct paths without whitespace in them, your code does work.

Comment: To add to what @KonradRudolph wrote you should use [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) for path manipulations so it will work on any OS.  Also what is in your `output` variable when you run your above command?

Comment: @sedavidw output returns emtpy.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, thanks, the path was a typo. It is always `/opt/annotations/`.

Comment: Just hardcode your array -- `['find', str(self._prefix), '-name', '*.txt', '-type', 'f', '-delete']`. More reliable than using `split()` -- works even if your `_prefix` contains characters that won't be split correctly, and doesn't mess up in presence of quotes meant to be consumed by a shell, as is the case with `"*.txt"` (which by the time it gets to `find` is just `*.txt`; the quotes are instructions _to the shell_, not to `find`)

Comment: (Also, the function's name and documentation are misleading; this doesn't run **bash** commands at all; try running any shell builtin and you'll see it fail. Even with `shell=True` your code uses `/bin/sh` instead of `bash` and so can't access commands that are built into and exclusive to bash, but with `shell=False` it uses no shell at all, so also can't work with redirections, command substitutions, globs... and commands that expect shell-like quote handling).

Comment: BTW, if you either go the `shlex.split()` approach or use a real shell (`shell=True`), be sure that when you use f-strings to generate a shell command, you use `shlex.quote()` to generate versions of your values that will unescape back to their original/intended content. So that might be `f'find {shlex.quote(self._prefix)} -name "*.txt" -type f -delete')` for your example here.

Comment: ...the above is only _sorta_ important with the `shlex.split()` approach -- stops someone who can change your prefix from making it actually delete text files under _two_ directories instead of just one, for example -- but if you used a real shell it would be security-critical; don't want a `$(rm -rf ~)` making it into your command and being executed by the shell as code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the quotes. You don't have files matching `"*.txt"`, but only files matching `*.txt`.

Pass your command *explicitly* as a list, instead of trying to generate a list from a string, to avoid this and other problems:

```
def _run_command(command_argv: list) -> str:
    logging.info(f"Running {command_argv}.")
    process = subprocess.Popen(command_argv, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    if error is not None:
        logging.exception(f"Error running command: {bash_command}")
        raise ValueError(error)
    return str(output)

_run_command(['find', str(self._prefix), '-name', '*.txt', '-type', 'f', '-delete'])
```

---

If you **insist** on taking arguments as a string, use `shlex.split()` to get POSIX sh-like (not bash-like) handling of quoted values:

```
def _run_command(shell_command: str) -> str:
    """
    Run a shell command, but without actually invoking any shell

    Args:
        shell_command: command to be executed.
    """
    logging.info(f"Running {shell_command}.")
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(shell_command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    if error is not None:
        logging.exception(f"Error running command: {shell_command}")
        raise ValueError(error)

    return str(output)
```

...but that only fixes the specific concern of quote removal; it doesn't make operations shell-compatible in any other respect.